# Post-apocalyptic novel featuring black female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, novel, apocalypse

In the 1970s, I read a sci-fi novel in high school, where the main character was a black girl, a point purposely not made clear until late in the book. It takes place in a post-apocalyptic (is there any other kind?) Earth. She meets a white boy, and they discover a helicopter, which, miracle-of-miracles, works! I don't remember more than that, except that I enjoyed the book. If that description rings any bells, could you tell me the title? (and, yes, I did numerous web searches, but, couldn't find anything even close) Thanks!

Comment: Good book, black female protagonist, 70s. If it was horribly depressing / brutal, the first place I'd look is at Octavia Butler.

Comment: "Is there any other kind?"  Frequently. 
As for the book, I'd again say Octavia Butler or maybe Delany.

Comment: The Octavia E. Butler novel similar to this, _Parable of the Sower_, came out in 1993.

Comment: Paul: The book I mentioned was neither depressing nor brutal.


Covertwalrus: I was being facetious.


Spencer: 1993 is well beyond the 70s.


Though I appreciate all your responses, I checked Ms. Butler's works, and none are even close to the book I described.

Comment: Someone on a different website found the answer:
"Day of the Drones" (1969) by A.M.Lightner.